# Getting started in the world of drone programming

Tags: ros, opencv, drone, parrot, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys, I'am new in this site but i think i will pretty active in the next few months!
My idea is program a drone so that it follows objects alone. I have some programming experience  but i don't yet have a drone.
I know that the Parrot drones can be programmed with ROS and i get the idea that people who get into this projects follow that path, i'am i correct?
I found out recently that it's also possible to program DJI drones, how does that work?

I need the drone to have around 30 minutes of battery(ideally more, but if not possible that will do). The camera needs to be decent as well and i would also like the drone to be robust. (not fun burning $$).

So based on the above what drone would you recommend me, and how should i tackle this? (i'am thinking i need to study computer vision and learn to use OpenCV, what more?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257182/getting-started-in-the-world-of-drone-programming/) by [sep_vanmarcke](https://answers.ros.org/users/29715/sep_vanmarcke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are new to drone programming, I would recommend you to start out with a simulator (unless you have many $$ to burn).

There is some options out there using the Gazebo simulator, check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwTnY-ZqNcM&ab_channel=RoyGaol it contains instructions on how to get it running in Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo:

(I reproduce the instructions here just for reference):

````
 -----------Install Ros indigo, Gazebo, Tum Simulator---------------

" Before install ROS and GAZEBO Ubuntu, you should install UBUNTU 14.0 in your machine " 

1. Install Git
- sudo apt-get install git

3. Instal ROS-GAZEBO
you can follow the instruction how to install of ROS 
- http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installati...


4. Install Tum Simulator
- You can follow the instruction in https://github.com/dougvk/tum_simulator or..

1. Create a workspace for the simulator

```
mkdir -p ~/tum_simulator_ws/src
cd ~/tum_simulator_ws/src
catkin_init_workspace
```
2. Download dependencies

```
git clone https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardron... # The AR.Drone ROS driver
git clone https://github.com/occomco/tum_simula...
cd ..
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
```
3. Build the simulator

```
catkin_make
```
4. Source the environment

```
source devel/setup.bash
```
How to run a simulation:

1. Run a simulation by executing a launch file in cvg_sim_gazebo package:

```
roslaunch cvg_sim_gazebo ardrone_testworld.launch
```
````

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2017-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sep_vanmarcke](https://answers.ros.org/users/29715/sep_vanmarcke/) on 2017-03-17**:
I will give that a go for the moment.

**Comment by [Manu](https://answers.ros.org/users/39851/manu/) on 2019-02-04**:
Excuse me, is it works with the latest ROS version(melodic)?.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2019-02-27**:
I haven't tried it myself, why don't you give it a try?